# TFS Best way to handle branches and project references

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, branch

I have the following TFS configuration

```
Root\
  Proj1\
    App1\
      ...
    App2\
      ...
  Proj2\
    Lib1\
      ...
    Lib2\
      ...
```

App1 and App2 both have project references to Lib1 and Lib2.
App1 does not reference App2, and Lib1 does not reference Lib2.

Now, I want to make changes to Lib1... but I want to branch it because the changes are drastic. These changes shouldn't require changes in either app1 or app2.

I created a branch Lib1Branch1 in TFS... but App1 and App2 both still reference Lib1 rather than lib1branch1... I don't want to manually re-reference the branch in each App (In actuality I have much more than just two).

When I used SVN, if I branched a project, and switched to that project, the local folders kept their original names and only the contents changed... thus building with one branch of the lib vs. building with the other only required that I switch branches and do a get-all... how do I get similar behavior using TFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding.

A Project is a self contained piece which is part of a larger thing called a solution.  For example, a single class library is one project.  It may reference other projects.

There are several ways to do branching.  Minor branches might just require branching a particular project within the solution (such as Lib1) while major changes might require branching the entire solution.

It sounds like what you need to do is change your TFS structure slightly, then branch the entire thing.  For example, the folder structure should probably be similar to the following:

```
Root  
  \1.0
    \Web Apps
        \App1
        \App2
    \Libraries
        \Lib1
        \Lib2
```

Then, when you branch, you take the entire 1.0 branch.  That way all references are preserved between the two branches.

Comment: Root is the TFS Collection, under root are two TFS Projects, in the first project is a set of Visual Studio SLNs for various applications, each of those applications reference various .proj files from the second TFS Porject (the libs project)
The second TFS Project has a set of Library Visual Studio SLNs. I want to branch a particular project file within a particular solution in the Libraries TFS Project...

Comment: @Paragon:  You might reread my answer.  I understand how it's been structured, it's just that the particular way it was structured isn't conducive to branching the way you are used to it.  Which means either the TFS items need to be restructured or you'll have to live with retargetting App1 because you are branching Lib1.  This isn't a TFS problem; rather it's just an issue with whoever setup your TFS server.

Comment: I set up the TFS server :) 
But, your saying that to make a change that doesn't affect the API of Lib1, I have to branch everything below 1.0? I could understand that if I were making a permanent branch, but I would expect to branch a bit more selectively than that. 
I did manage to find a work around though. If you make the branch at Lib1 to Lib1_Branch1, then remap Lib1_Branch1 to the same local directory that Lib1 had occupied you can work on Lib1_Branch1 alongside Lib2. Then, after checking in changes, set the mapping back to normal to do the merge.